# Intersection of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, field-theory

I have been searching for some question like that but hadn't found.

Let $I$ and $J$ be intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(I\cap \mathbb{Q})\cap(J \cap \mathbb{Q})$ = $\varnothing$

Prove: $I \cap J$ has at most one element.

I tried to assume negatively that there are two elements in $I \cap J$ - hoping I'll get they both equal finally. But I didn't succeed to find a way showing this.

Comment: Hi. You may use the following facts : 1) between two irrationals, there is at least one (in fact an infinity of) rational ; 2) if $(x,y)\in I$ where $I$ is an interval, then $[x,y]\subset I$.

Comment: Yes, we solved it yesterday. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: if two elements are in an interval $I$, any element between them is also in $I$. Also, note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let $a, b \in I \cap J$ such that $a \ne b$. Now, we know that the $\mathbb{Q}$ are densed in $\mathbb{R}$ then there is $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q \in (a,b)$.

But I don't know what's next...

Comment: Note that $(I \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cap (J \cap \mathbb{Q}) = (I \cap J) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. You want to get a contradiction by showing this set is non-empty.

Comment: So I have already shown the contradiction in my steps above, no?

Comment: Yup! The element $q$ is in that set.